# Tablesort sorts number as string

Tags: php, jquery

I've got a problem that I've managed to identify but I can't seem to be able to fix. Recently I've started using the [tablesorter pluggin](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) and overall it was a great time saver. However the sorting doesn't work when I use the php function [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php).

I've got a php [for loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) that prints all the `tbody` rows and if I print a `td` as:

```
<td id="<?php echo 'cost_'.($i + 1); ?>" class="highlight_cells" align="right"><?php echo $results[$i]['AvgPrice'];?></td>
```

Then the sorting works, however with the next code:

```
<td id="<?php echo 'cost_'.($i + 1); ?>" class="highlight_cells" align="right"><?php echo number_format($results[$i]['AvgPrice'], 2, ',', ' ');?></td>
```

The sorting treats the formated number and orders it as a string. The results are something like:

```
normal print:         formated print:
25.0002               135,22
91.15                 25,00
135.2178              91,15
```

The reason that I need to use the [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) is because I'm printing money values. I've also tried to change the comma with a dot but I've got the same results. Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this

```
<td id="<?php echo 'cost_'.($i + 1); ?>" class="highlight_cells" align="right"><?php echo number_format($results[$i]['AvgPrice'], 2, '.', '');?></td>
```

Comment: Yeah, it works by removing the space. But I've wanted to keep it, as it's easier to read. For now I'll keep it as you pointed out, I guess I need to change the tablesorter to add this particular case. Thanks.